# How to upload a canvas image from javascript to Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am trying to send this toDataURL image to the server through AJAX. Unfortunately, every time it sends - no matter how I finagle it - I can only get either a 403 Forbidden error, a javascript error, or - at best - an empty dictionary item, while the other fields are accurate. Any ideas?

javascript

```
function SaveImage(n){

   var imageFile = document.getElementById("img-file"+n);
    // Set that you want to download the image when link is clicked
    imageFile.setAttribute('download', 'image.png');
    // Reference the image in canvas for download
    imageFile.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL());

    addMeme(imageFile);

}
function addMeme(n){
var f= n;



var patch = '{% url "testing" %}';
var post_data = {
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken':"{{ csrf_token }}",
 imageBase64:f,
 g: 'jjj',
};


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: patch,
  data:post_data,
 dataType: 'json',


success: function(data){


}
```

});}

views.py

```
def testing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response_json = request.POST
        response_json = json.dumps(response_json)
        data = json.loads(response_json)

        print(data['imageBase64'])


    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: `canvas` is coming from where ?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add a ProcessData: false to the AJAX call. I upvoted you for taking your time to respond, though. Thank you!